# Incrementing matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Im looking to define a 2xn matrix where the first row increments from 0 by 1, and the second row is all 1's. This is the shortest answer i have found so far but i wanted to know if it could be done in one operation?

```
A=[0:1:(n-1);
   0:1:(n-1)];

A(2,:)=1;
```

Comment: the vector `0:1:n` has `n+1` elements and not `n`...

Comment: sorry, yes you are right that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it

```
 A = vertcat( 0:(n-1), ones(1,n) );
```

Comment: @JordanCartwright, note that you can do `A = [0:(n-1); ones(1,n)]` too. I.e. use `;` as `vertcat`. But, someone prefers `vertcat` because you can immediately see that you want to concatenate it vertically.